# Check if async request is finished, using loopj android async

Tags: android, asynchronous, get

I am developing an android app that uses Android Async. I am using this library called [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

I made a method for a GET request

```
public String getVenues(String token) throws Exception {
    AsyncHttpClient venuesReq = new AsyncHttpClient();
    venuesReq.addHeader("Authorization", "Token token=" + token);
    venuesReq.get(mainAct.httpRequestURL + "/venues", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            venues = response;
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
           // Completed the request (either success or failure)
       }
    return venues;
}
```

but when I call `getVenues("token")` the return is null, but when I try to call `getVenues("token")` after few seconds there are now results for venues.

I know that I am using async request so the venues doesn't return immediately.

Now what I want is, when I call `getVenues("token")` method there should be a returned response for the GET Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use interface here take a look at this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21773406/472336

Your class from where you are listening/asking for asyntask result need to impliment interface and call that interface method from asyntask..

Hope this helps

Comment: That solution only works if you have a class that extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> but I already extends my class on a Fragment

Comment: No you can impliment this solution with Fragment too. check this link http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    OnArticleSelectedListener mListener;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
        }
    }
    ...
}